# automation of the Rolling deployment with (Eureka, microservice)

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I did begin to learn , how i can do the automatisation of Rolling Deployment or Rolling Update of Service. I use Springboot microservice and Eureka for register. I explain now what i want to do. I have three Service, which are registed on the Eureka-server(picture):

[image]

After I will add a new Service (update of the Service I V 2.0) :

[image]

but i want to automate the unregister of Service I V 1.0 on Eureka and the Register of Service I V 2.0 on Eureka :)

can you Help me please ? :) , I have no Ideal how i can do it :(

thanks for your Answer :).